# Mapkit - Existe como localizar amigos dentro desta ferramenta?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Ja utilizo mapkit para desenvolvimento no iOS, mas gostaria de saber se alguém conhece como no código para adicionar amigos, mostrar no mapa outras pessoas próximas.

PS. ou mesmo um código de exemplo para esta função, agradeço.

Comment: Acredito que não exista algum mecanismo dentro do `MapKit` que já faça isso. Você precisaria implementar um servidor/backend que conheça todas as localizações das pessoas e retorne-as para você exibir no mapa.

Comment: entendi, o app FindMyFrieds seria um exemplo disso.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe nenhum recurso nativo do `MapKit` que você possa fazer isso.

Uma boa prática para isso seria montar uma base de dados que colete as informações de localização dos outros usuários. A partir dessa base você efetuar requisições para obter estas informações. Por exemplo, o serviço do aplicativo coleta a localização e envia para o servidor. Outros usuários para obter tais informações fazem a requisição.

Uma segunda opção ainda é uma espécie de comunicação *peer-to-peer* entre os dispositivos (que não lhe dou total certeza de que seja funcional em tal ocasião), fazendo a troca de informações com as localizações, o que na minha opinião acredito ser totalmente **inviável** nesta situação.

Espero ter ajudado.